Unable to get Cookie in nextjs that is set by laravel api in my browser?
I have a Next.js application where I am trying to set up Axios to include the CSRF token automatically in all non-GET requests. I have written the following code to retrieve the XSRF-TOKEN from cookies and set it in the request headers. However, I'm facing issues with retrieving.I am Calling api that set Cookies in my browser
Here is my code:
function getCookie(name) {   const cookie = document.cookie
    .split("; ")
    .find((item) => item.startsWith(`${name}=`));   console.log(document.cookie); // Debug: check what cookies are present if (!cookie) return null;

  return decodeURIComponent(cookie.split("=")[1]); // Fixed: Correctly split the cookie value }

const axios = Axios.create({   baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,   headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",   },   withCredentials: true,   withXSRFToken: true, });

axios.interceptors.request.use(async (req) => {   if (req.method === "get") return req;

  let csrfToken = getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");   if (!csrfToken) {
    await axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
    csrfToken = getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");   }   req.headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = csrfToken;   return req; });

export default axios;

Issues:
Retrieving the Cookie: The getCookie function does not always retrieve the XSRF-TOKEN correctly.
Setting the Cookie: Even after successfully calling /sanctum/csrf-cookie, the XSRF-TOKEN is sometimes still not present.
What I've Tried:
Debugging document.cookie: Added a console log to check the cookies present in the document.
Manual Request to /sanctum/csrf-cookie: Tried manually hitting the endpoint to ensure the CSRF cookie is being set.
Questions:
Is there a better way to retrieve cookies in a Next.js application?
Are there specific browser settings or CORS configurations that might be interfering with cookie handling?
How can I ensure that the CSRF token is reliably set and retrieved across different environments and browsers?
I am attaching Image of Cookies Present in Headers


I've been working on this same problem the past couple of days. Did you manage to solve it? From what I understand, axios is supposed to send the X-XSRF-TOKEN automatically. You can also set xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN" manually if you need to but that didn't help me.

Update: my problem was mostly due to my laravel app, and electron app being on different domains. laravel was on folder.test and electron app was localhost:5173. once I put laravel on localhost:8000 and changed SESSION_DOMAIN and SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS both to localhost it started working. I didn't have to set the X-XSRF-TOKEN in axios at all.  Idk if this helps your case but I thought i'd share in the off chance it does.

Yes You were in my case also the problem was on laravel side .Probelm was laravel sending cookie expiry time according to server time but both server and client side hosted on different domains so basically it was a expiry time conflict when cookie saved in browser it was expired technically according to server and client side time diff. so removing expiry time and adding max age solved the problem
